# nReco.Video Converter ffMpeg Error

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture

I am using Nreco Video Converter for take video thumbnail on my MVC project. App is working correctly on local but it shows error on live host

Error is

**Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts********\httpdocs\bin\ffmpeg.exe' is denied.**

I did search this file in my code and host bin folder but I can't found. NReco's site says

**Simple and easy to use video conversion .NET library: all you need is one assembly (FFMpeg is embedded)**

There is no ffmpeg.exe file in  local and host bin folder or anywhere.

How can i fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

VideoConverter is a .net wrapper for ffmpeg tool (I'm an author of this library) and ffmpeg.exe is extracted into app bin folder (default location) on first use. On your live host asp.net process cannot write to app bin folder; this may be fixed by specifying another location, for example:

```
var ffmpeg = new FFMpegConverter();
ffmpeg.FFMpegToolPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
```

Comment: I am having same problem. Even after specifying other folder same error occurs

Comment: @vaibhavshah you need to specify a folder that is writable by your ASP.NET app. In some environments, "App_Data" is also read-only.